# Sorting multi-dictionary in python

Tags: python, associative-array

I have a datastructure like this:

```
poll = {
  'LINK' : {'MoonRaccoon' : 1, 'TheDirtyTree' : 1},
  'ZRX' : {'MoonRaccoon' : 1, 'Dontcallmeskaface' : 1, 'TheDirtyTree' : 1},  
  'XRP' : {'Dontcallmeskaface' : 1},
  'XLM' : {'aeon' : 1, 'Bob' : 1} 
}
```

I want it to ultimately print like this ordered by the number of who have requested each, then ticker symbol alphabetically, then the users also alphabetically

```
!pollresults

ZRX : Dontcallmeskaface, MoonRaccoon, TheDirtyTree
LINK : MoonRaccoon, TheDirtyTree
XLM : aeon, Bob
XRP: Dontcallmeskaface
```

Anyone really good at sorting that could help me do this..  I'm really new to python and super rusty at coding in general.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here you get a oneliner:**

```
print (sorted(poll.items(), key = lambda item : len(list(item[1].keys())), reverse = True))
```

Output:

```
[('ZRX', {'MoonRaccoon': 1, 'Dontcallmeskaface': 1, 'TheDirtyTree': 1}), ('LINK', {'MoonRaccoon': 1, 'TheDirtyTree': 1}), ('XLM', {'aeon': 1, 'Bob': 1}), ('XRP', {'Dontcallmeskaface': 1})]
```

To pretty print:

```
lst = sorted(poll.items(), key = lambda item : len(list(item[1].keys())), reverse = True)

for elem in lst:
    print (elem[0],":"," ".join(elem[1].keys()))
```

**And because I really like oneliners, everything in one line!**

```
print ("\n".join([" : ".join([elem[0]," ".join(list(elem[1].keys()))]) for elem in sorted(poll.items(), key = lambda item : len(list(item[1].keys())), reverse = True)]))
```

Output:

```
ZRX : MoonRaccoon Dontcallmeskaface TheDirtyTree
LINK : MoonRaccoon TheDirtyTree
XLM : aeon Bob
XRP : Dontcallmeskaface
```

Comment: Good, think about accepting my answer if that helps ;)

Comment: i would but i already accepted the previous response which is the one i used..  but I did like yours as well.

Comment: this is actually really good.. i'm going to try it out.

Comment: Thanks so much for that most elegant solution.   may i please direct you to this other question?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65695667/empty-set-trying-to-build-dictionary-for-discord-bot

Comment: Thanks again for all your help.   you were totally right that it was because the Repl database is probably some kind of hash table flat file and you have to overwrite it.   I have another challenge for you..  can you do an alphabetical pre-sort on the ticker so that the ones with the same number of votes are alphabetical?

Comment: Well, most people will certainly disagree but the more you use mainstream python, the less you are likely to fall into some kind of fork specific problems! I would like to answer your question, sure. But for that you need to create a new one. Stack doesn't allow for new questions in comments like this. Create it, I'll see it ;)

Comment: sure ok.   it was actually part of the original spec but i didn't do a good job describing that.   but i thought about it after and realized maybe order of posting might be more relevant than alphabetical anyway..  which should be what it is in now..

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries can't really be sorted, but for the purposes of printing, this can be done.

```py
poll = {
  'LINK' : {'MoonRaccoon' : 1, 'TheDirtyTree' : 1},
  'ZRX' : {'MoonRaccoon' : 1, 'Dontcallmeskaface' : 1, 'TheDirtyTree' : 1},  
  'XRP' : {'Dontcallmeskaface' : 1},
  'XLM' : {'aeon' : 1, 'Bob' : 1} 
}

def print_polls(poll):
    for ticker in sorted(poll, key=lambda t: sum(poll[t].values()), reverse=True):
        print(f"{ticker}: {', '.join(sorted(poll[ticker]))}")
```

This will give you the output you're looking for

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think i want `Bob` before `aeon` though.   I would want it sorted alphabetically preferably.    I will give this a try.

Comment: TypeError: join() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: @RobinGoodheart just get rid of the key. I placed the parens in the wrong spot

Comment: i need this in a string so it can be sent to the discord chat.   instead of printing can i just say result +=  and return result to send it to the discord output?

Comment: @RobinGoodheart sure thing. You're going to want to add a `\n` character at the end of the string to format multiple lines

Answer (score 1):

1. count the votes in `poll`, get `d`
2. sort `d` decreasingly
3. get poll result in the order of step 2, and handle sorting the name lists

```py
d = [[k, len(v)] for k, v in poll.items()]
d.sort(key=lambda name_vote: (-name_vote[-1],name_vote[0]))
pollresults = [name + ' : ' + ', '.join(sorted(poll[name].keys(), key=str.lower)) for name,vote in d]
```

result:

```py
>>> pollresults
['ZRX : Dontcallmeskaface, MoonRaccoon, TheDirtyTree', 'LINK : MoonRaccoon, TheDirtyTree', 'XLM : aeon, Bob', 'XRP : Dontcallmeskaface']
```