# Empty set trying to build dictionary for discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py, associative-array, replit

I am trying to build a dictionary for a discord bot.   The data structure will look like this:

```
poll = {
  'LINK' : {'MoonRaccoon' : 1, 'TheDirtyTree' : 1},
  'ZRX' : {'MoonRaccoon' : 1, 'Dontcallmeskaface' : 1, 'TheDirtyTree' : 1},  
  'XRP' : {'Dontcallmeskaface' : 1},
  'XLM' : {'aeon' : 1, 'Bob' : 1} 
}
```

this will then be saved to db["poll"] in the Repl.it database. https://docs.repl.it/misc/database
which i guess is just a persistent dictionary?   (I don't think this is relevant to the issue I'm having though)

users will enter their vote like

`!v ZRX`

The bot then needs to add that "vote" to the dictionary.

The code I am trying to get to do that goes like so:

update:

```
def update_poll(ticker,requestor):
  vote = {ticker : {requestor : 1}}

for (key, value) in vote.items():
    if 'poll' not in db.keys():
        db['poll'] = []
    if key in db['poll'].keys():
        db['poll'][key].append(value)
    else:
        db['poll'][key] = value
```

it's not going well though..   Some have previously suggested using `defaultdict` but i honestly have not been able to wrap my brain around it yet.  python novice here..

any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: So you want a persistant dictionnary with?

Comment: Repl.it offers the persistent dictionary with the `db` variable..   i just have to figure out how to work with it.   seems to work fine when i load it with the test set of data above.. not so much when i try to add items one by one.

Comment: Just one question. Why don't you just pickle a normal dict in a file to preserve it?

Comment: btw, once i figure out how to add items one by one I will also want to be able to take them away one by one.   basically remove usernames from the ticker symbol dictionary until there are 0 items in it in which case the ticker symbol key will be deleted.

Comment: This is my first time taking a crack at building a discord bot and i honestly don't know enough about it..  found a tutorial on building a bot on Repl,it so trying to work with the tools they offer first.   If I end up running the bot somewhere else i guess i will need another solution.  it works fine with the above test data structure so it seems my issue is with manipulating that data structure.

Comment: Ok, just edit your post I would like to see what print(db) yields. I have no knowledge of repl stuff.

Comment: i don't think this issue is with repl stuff..  it's a library.  i have one of these at the top.. `from replit import db`. but i'm not building the data structure properly with the user input.   everything is hunky dory if i just load that above data structure into db["poll"].  and now i can sort it.  i can restart the bot and it perists.  i can delete the whole thing and reload it.     but i still can't build and manipulate the data structure one by one.  If I can build it I can save it to db["poll"] and that persists.

Comment: I did a print of `db` and it just gave me what looked like an URL to an API with a really long token attached to it.   it didn't even show me db["poll"] although i can print it separately so i know it's there somehow..  through the API library i guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227248/discussion-between-synthase-and-robin-goodheart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ticker = 'a'; requestor = 'b'
vote = {ticker : {requestor : 1}}
db = {}
for (key, value) in vote.items():
    if 'poll' not in db.keys():
        db['poll'] = {}
    if key in db['poll'].keys():
        db['poll'][key].append(value)
    else:
        db['poll'][key] = value
```

Comment: hmm.. that does look promising

Comment: `   for (key, value) in vote.items():
NameError: name 'vote' is not defined `